# firebase does not catch errors

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to get the error to work but for some reason, it doesn't say so.
I did when the user put the phone number it will find it, and if he finds it he will return the doc data and the id, And it is working.
although the err does not work.

```
const onSubmit = (data) => {
    const phoneExists = docRef.collection('Guests').where("guestPhone", '==', data.phonenumber).get();
    phoneExists.then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
            console.log(doc.id, "=>", doc.data());
            // docRef.collection('Guests').doc(doc.id).update({
            //     numOfInvites: data.guestsnumber,
            //     confirmed: true
            // })
        })
    }).catch(err => {
        console.log('Error getting documents', err);
        console.error('Error getting documents', err);
        
    })
}
```

it's not return anything while the phone number does not exist in the document.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firebase only returns an error when there was a problem in getting the request like the internet was down or the user didn't have enough permission to get the document. If you want to check if no document exists, you can use querySnapshot.empty which returns a boolean

`const empty = querySnapshot.empty`

You can also use the size operator to check the number of documents returned

`const numberOfDocuments = querySnapshot.size`

You can Learn more about all properties available here
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot#properties_1

Comment: Thank you very much. I just add if(querySnapshot.empty) return error and it's working just fine. Thank you.